# Datadog: Notify about every new log-item with error-level

Tags: datadog

Is it possible to configure datadog to notify about each new error that got logged?

I know how to set a threshold for a specified period and how to send the error-count for instance to slack. But I am searching for a possibility to send the actual error rather than the number of errors.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible today, but that is in Datadog's plans for development.

What you can do as a workaround, though, is add a link to your logs explorer with the query that triggered the monitor alert, so you can get a quick reference to what were the logs that triggered it.

This link, for example, would quickly scope you to the error logs over the last 15 minutes: `https://app.datadoghq.com/logs?live=true&query=status%3Aerror&stream_sort=desc`

And markdown is supported, so you can keep your monitor messages prettier without long links in the messages. Like so:
`[Check the error logs here](https://app.datadoghq.com/logs?live=true&query=status%3Aerror&stream_sort=desc)`

Comment: is this still current status